# mouseDragged not returning appropriate button down

Tags: java, swing, awt, mouse-listeners

How can I know the button that was pressed from within a `mouseDragged` event?

I'm having an issue in `mouseDragged()` because the received `MouseEvent` returns 0 for `getButton()`. I have no problem with the mouse location, or even detecting mouse clicks. The `mouseClicked()` event returns the appropriate button for `getButton()`.

Any suggestions on how I can do this? I assume I could do a work-around using `mouseClicked`, or `mousePressed`, but I would prefer to keep this all within `mouseDragged`.

Thanks for your time and answers.

Comment: Can you drag with right mouse button, i only dragged with the left mouse button

Comment: I tested both buttons, and it sent 0 for both buttons.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As pointed out in comments and other answers, SwingUtilities provides three methods for cases like this, which should work for all MouseEvents:

```
SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(aMouseEvent);
SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(aMouseEvent);
SwingUtilities.isMiddleMouseButton(aMouseEvent);
```

As for what the problem with your approach is, the javadoc of `getButton()` says:

> Returns which, if any, of the mouse buttons has changed state.

Since the state of the button doesn't change while it is being held down, `getButton()` will usually return `NO_BUTTON` in `mouseDragged`. To check the state of buttons and modifiers like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, etc. in `mouseDragged`, you can use `getModifiersEx()`. As an example, the below code checks that `BUTTON1` is down but `BUTTON2` is not:

```
int b1 = MouseEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK;
int b2 = MouseEvent.BUTTON2_DOWN_MASK;
if ((e.getModifiersEx() & (b1 | b2)) == b1) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: You're right concerning the first part (javadoc), but I think using `SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton()` is even better (see other answer)

Comment: @xav Since this is already the accepted answer I added the SwingUtilities approach for better visibility (and expanded on why you might choose `getModifiersEx` instead).

Answer (score 7):

Jacob's right that `getButton()` doesn't get you the button by design. However, I found a cleaner solution than bit operations on `getModifiersEx()`, that you can also use within `mouseDragged`:

```
if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(theMouseEvent)) {
    //do something
}
```

Similar methods exist for the middle button and the right button.

Comment: You're right. And I guess this is also better for portability than `getModifiersEx()` (MacOS, Linux, ...)

Comment: @xav In terms of portability, [getModifiersEx()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#getModifiersEx()) is exactly the same (very portable), because the `isLeftMouseButton(..)` &co. methods are implemented in terms of it. See [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.java#SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton%28java.awt.event.MouseEvent%29). These are simply more readable convenience methods.

Answer (score 2):

```
int currentMouseButton = -1;
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    currentMouseButton = e.getButton();
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    currentMouseButton = -1;
}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    if (currentMouseButton == 3) {
        System.out.println("right button");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be possibly a problem of your java sandbox.

The following code works well all the time (almost, as you can see).

```
@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    e.getButton();
}
```

Please try your code on a different machine.