# Java AWT: MouseMotionListener cannot distinguish mouse buttons

Tags: java, user-interface, awt

So, in the code provided, I'm printing out the type of button that is pressed by using two interfaces, viz., MouseListener and MouseMotionListener. How do I make MouseMotionListener's mouseDragged method to differentiate the button type just like the MouseListener's MousePressed method ?

Below is the code, followed by the console output.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

class Mouse extends Frame implements MouseMotionListener, MouseListener {
    Label l;
    Color color = Color.red;

    public Mouse() {
        l = new Label();
        l.setBounds(20, 40, 100, 20);
        add(l);

        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        setSize(400, 400);
        setLayout(null);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("MouseMotionListener:"+e.getButton());
        l.setText("X=" + e.getX() + " Y=" + e.getY());
    }
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("MouseListener:"+e.getButton());
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        l.setText("X=" + e.getX() + " Y=" + e.getY());
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    }


    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

}
```

Output:

```
MouseListener:1
MouseListener:1
MouseMotionListener:0
MouseMotionListener:0
MouseMotionListener:0
MouseMotionListener:0
MouseMotionListener:0
MouseMotionListener:0
MouseMotionListener:0
MouseMotionListener:0
MouseListener:2
MouseListener:2
MouseMotionListener:0
MouseMotionListener:0
MouseMotionListener:0
MouseMotionListener:0
MouseMotionListener:0
MouseMotionListener:0
MouseMotionListener:0
MouseMotionListener:0
MouseMotionListener:0
MouseMotionListener:0
MouseMotionListener:0
MouseListener:3
MouseListener:3
MouseMotionListener:0
MouseMotionListener:0
MouseMotionListener:0
MouseMotionListener:0
MouseMotionListener:0
MouseMotionListener:0
MouseMotionListener:0
MouseMotionListener:0
MouseMotionListener:0
MouseMotionListener:0
MouseMotionListener:0
```

Comment: Instead of printing `e.getButton()`, print the event’s *modifiers* using `InputEvent.getModifiersExText(e.getModifiersEx())`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are actually using Swing (since there in no need to use AWT).

You can use the `SwingUtilities` class to check which button is pressed:

```
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println( SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e) );
    System.out.println("MouseMotionListener:"+e.getButton());
    l.setText("X=" + e.getX() + " Y=" + e.getY());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can implement the *[MouseInputListener](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/event/MouseInputListener.html)* interface, which conveniently implements both *MouseListener* and *MouseMotionListener*.

Regarding your inquiry, here is a similar question and answer.
*[StackOverflow – mouseDragged not returning appropriate button down](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18172343/17758716)*.

It looks like the framework recommends utilizing the *[SwingUtilities](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html)* class for this situation.

Specifically, the following 3 methods.

- *[isLeftMouseButton](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#isLeftMouseButton(java.awt.event.MouseEvent))*
- *[isMiddleMouseButton](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#isMiddleMouseButton(java.awt.event.MouseEvent))*
- and *[isRightMouseButton](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#isRightMouseButton(java.awt.event.MouseEvent))*

Here is an example.

```java
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("l= " + SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e));
    System.out.println("m= " + SwingUtilities.isMiddleMouseButton(e));
    System.out.println("r= " + SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e));
    l.setText("X=" + e.getX() + " Y=" + e.getY());
}
```

Output

```
MouseListener:1
l= true
m= false
r= false
MouseListener:3
l= false
m= false
r= true
```

Additionally, here are two *Java* tutorials, on implementing *mouse listeners*, and *mouse-motion listeners*.

- *[How to Write a Mouse Listener (The Java™ Tutorials > Creating a GUI With Swing > Writing Event Listeners)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)*.
- *[How to Write a Mouse-Motion Listener (The Java™ Tutorials > Creating a GUI With Swing > Writing Event Listeners)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html)*.

Comment: *It looks like the framework recommends utilizing the SwingUtilities class for this situation.* - already suggested hours ago.

Comment: @camickr, there is no marked answer as of now.